# JavaScript/jQuery: Animate li movement within a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got some code that's basically identical to the jQuery UI Sortable example here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default

This allows users to re-order LI elements within a UL. I've now run into a situation, though, where I want to animate the LIs changing position... basically as if the user had dragged them herself. This is proving to be a lot more difficult than I'd expected, since I'm not animating a change that can be expressed in CSS, so jQuery's animate() isn't going to help.

I *could* solve the problem by doing some math and absolutely positioning the list elements, but that seems downright ugly. Is there an elegant way to animate my list elements moving around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I posted some script on animating an object after it was dragged in [this paste bin](http://pastebin.me/c754509741569a3708d94d65878db13d).

Essentially, you animate the clone after the element is dropped:

```
 $("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
   $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
   var x = ui.helper.clone();
   x.appendTo('body')
    // move clone to original drag point
    .css({position: 'absolute',top: ui.draggable.position().top,left:ui.draggable.position().left})
    .animate({
     // animate clone to droppable target
     top: $(this).position().top, left: $(this).position().left},
     // animation time
     1500,
     // callback function - once animation is done
     function(){
      x.find('.caption').text("I'm being munched on!");
      ui.draggable.addClass('fade');
      // remove clone after 500ms
      setTimeout(function(){ x.remove(); }, 500)
     }
    );
   // remove the helper, so it doesn't animate backwards to the starting position (built into the draggable script)
   ui.helper.remove();
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a helper `div` and animate that into position, then move the actual `li` and destroy the helper.

You can use`$('#li').clone()` to fill your helper, then absolutely position the helper `div` using the position from `$('#li').offset()`.  Animate the helper to the new position (`$('#target').offset()`), destroy the helper (`.remove()`), and then reorder your `<li>`s.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/index.html), which lets you specify another set of `<li>` nodes to replace the current ones with and it'll handle whatever animation is necessary to transform the existing list into the new one.

The library expects you to have another `<ul>` or `<ol>` around (which you'd keep hidden from the user) to represent the new order, but you could automate the creation of a temporary list for that purpose so that the client code can just supply a new order for the same nodes. It does need to somehow swap the nodes with new ones though, which may cause complications if your code expects the nodes to stay the same.